# "Error: [vuex] actions should be function or object with "handler" function but "actions.default" is {}" after updating Vue & Vuex

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I made the following npm package updates to my project:

```
vuex: 2.3.1 -> 3.0.0
vue: 2.4.2 -> 2.5.2
vue-router: 2.7.0 -> 3.0.1
```

(and some more but I don't consider them relevant to this issue)

And now I get this error upon starting up my webpage:

> Error: [vuex] actions should be function or object with "handler"
>   function but "actions.default" is {}

I am not so sure why, I read the Vuex changelog and the syntax does not really seem to have changed, but for some reason my code crashes.

Upon examining this issue closer I found out that the error is generated by a failed assertion in a file called vuex.esm.js:

```
function assert (condition, msg) {
    if (!condition) { throw new Error(("[vuex] " + msg)) }
}
```

The code worked fine before updating the packages, there is probably something I am missing here. I am happy to provide any code that might help understand the issue better.

Thanks!

EDIT:
Here is the Call stack that leads to the error:
[image: Call stack]

Comment: many details are missing.... what is the configuration of your program? webpack boilerplate?  how did u configure vuex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I experienced the same error in my unit tests. I just added a empty `handler` function to my actions and it worked after that...

```
const state = { auth: { authenticated: false } };
const actions = { auth: { handler: () => {}, logout: () => sinon.stub() } };
let store;
beforeEach(() => {
   store = new Vuex.Store({
     state,
     actions,
   });
});
```

Comment: Yes! Adding some a random action to my action.js file fixed it for me!

Comment: >.< But why does this fix the issue... It just helped me but I don't get why.